# Why is Segmentation fault happening?

Tags: c

```
int     main(int    argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\tpartner1 (nameIndex)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (num < 0 || num > 2) {
        printf("nameIndex must be in[0, 1, 2]");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

**output**

```
./parent1

Segmentation fault
```

Im getting Segmentation fault and I am not sure why this is happening. I know the second if statement is working fine because if I do input
***./partner1 4*** or ***./partner1 -1***, the output is

```
nameIndex must be in[0, 1, 2]
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: With no extra command-line arguments, `argv[1]` will be `NULL`. That line should only come after you've checked the number of arguments.

Comment: Don't attempt to access more arguments in `argv` than the `argc` count indicates.

Comment: You need to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and also, your program is missing a `}` at the end so this shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @ThomasJager Oh wow I swtiched the line as you said and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please create an answer.

Comment: @ThomasJager Please submit your comment as the answer. Someone said "Please create an answer" so I thought I was suppose to do that. Im new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `int num = atoi(argv[1]);` to below the `argc` check. That way, you'll only check `argv[1]` if you know it exists.

```
int     main(int    argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\tpartner1 (nameIndex)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int num = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (num < 0 || num > 2) {
        printf("nameIndex must be in[0, 1, 2]");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `argv` argument of `main` is a pointer to an array of `argc` pointers to strings, followed by a `NULL` pointer. `argv[0]` points to a C-string of the program's name, and `argv[1]` to `argv[argc - 1]` will point to the command-line arguments.

For example, if you execute a program like `./program hello world`, `argc` would be `3`, and `argv` be a pointer to an array that looks like:

```
+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------+
| <pointer to "program"> | <pointer to "hello"> | <pointer to "world"> | NULL |
+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------+
```

If you've confirmed that `argc == 3`, then you know that you can access the strings pointed-to by `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, and `argv[2]`.

With no arguments, executing `./program`, you'll have something like:

```
+------------------------+------+
| <pointer to "program"> | NULL |
+------------------------+------+
```

You can see that `argv[1]` is a `NULL` pointer, which can't be dereferenced (you can't access the data to which it points).

The function `atoi` will access the string to which the argument points, and that can't be `NULL`.

You should always check the value of `argc` and/or step through the `argv` array one at a time, checking for `NULL`. Your code will access `argv[1]` before it checks the value of `argc`, causing the `NULL` pointer dereference which leads to the crash.

The line with `atoi` should be moved to after the point where you check `argc`.